# can't make ScrollViewer vertical scrollbar appear

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

In a Windows Phone 8 app, I have a simple example of a `ScrollViewer` with an `ItemsControl` inside

```
<ScrollViewer>
   <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

I can swipe up and down and the ItemsControl scrolls accordingly but I am not able to see the vertical scroll-bar.

I do not have any Style applied for ScrollViewers, this is a simple app.
Since the default of `VerticalScrollBarVisibility` is set to `auto` shouldn't the scroll-bar be visible?
I am confused, I tried to set it explicitly and it still doesn't work.
How to make it visible?

Answer (score 0):

Is the ItemsControl height actually bigger than the ScrollViewer (thus hiding some items)?

The scrollbars only show up if there are actually hidden items that can only be reached by scrolling.

Comment: Yes, the ItemsControl is bigger. I mentioned I am able to swipe and scroll the items up and down.

Comment: Is the `ScrollViewer` inside a panorama or pivot page? I don't see the behavior you're describing in my device/emulator...

Comment: lol, I think I need a break, I am too tired. my page background is white and that's why I can't see the scrollbar. can't believe I wasted both of our times on this, I'm sorry